# Laravel 5 One To Many Relation Form Model Binding

Tags: forms, laravel, one-to-many, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel the first time and am working on an application with which I can generate invoices. Each invoice can have multiple positions. This means there is a one to many relation.

When creating a new invoice there are the inputs for the first position and via ajax the inputs to add more positions can be added.
I use an array for the positions and make a random index.

```
<?php $c = rand(); ?>

{!! Form::text('position['.$c.'][title]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
{!! Form::textarea('position['.$c.'][description]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

This works perfectly fine so far.
Now when it comes to editing an invoice the problem arises. What do I have to do to get the Form-Model Binding working?

Now I check how many positions I have and load the snippet with the position inputs that often and pass in the data.

```
@foreach( $document->positions as $position)
    @include('documents._position', [$position])
@endforeach
```

But the values don't appear in the input fields. What do I have to do to get this working?

And a second thing would be how can I sync the positions? I now just delete the existing ones after editing an invoice and make new ones. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass data to Sub-view you need to do it in this format

```
@include('view.name', ['some' => 'data'])
```

or you code will look right this

```
@foreach( $document->positions as $position)
    @include('documents._position', ['position' => $position])
@endforeach
```

Therefore, you can user `$position` in the Sub-view

```
{!! Form::text("position[$position->id][title]", $position->title, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
{!! Form::textarea("position[$position->id][description]", $position->description, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

source: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates#other-blade-control-structures

Comment: What do you mean by "you can use $position in the Sub-view"? What do I have to make to get the values applied to the inputs? The names of the inputs are like this name="project[*random*][title]"

Comment: You should not use the random value for editing but use position_id instead. Otherwise you will not know which line need to be updated.

Comment: Yes, updating is one thing - I need the random value for new positions, but can avoid them for existing positions. The other thing is, that the values don't appear in the inputs. Even if I use the position_id - like name="position[5][title]" Do you have an idea how I can manage this?

Comment: I updated my code. Just replace `null`  with the value like `$position->title` or `$position->description`.